# Restrict access to pages for some users

Tags: c#, asp.net, database

Got question regarding access restriction for specific users to pages. I know i can do that inside web.config but is it proper way in my case when i am using database authentication or it should be another way? How i can achieve that? Waiting your feedback.

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Authenticate against the list stored in db
        if (AuthenticateUser(txtLogin.Text, txtPassword.Text))
        {
            //Create the authentication cookie and redirect the user to welcome page
            FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromLoginPage(txtLogin.Text, chkBoxRememberMe.Checked);
        }
        else
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "Invalid Username and/or password";
        }
    }

    // TODO : zaimplementuj blokade konta po x blednych probach logowania: ASP.NET part 93
    private bool AuthenticateUser(string username, string password)
    {
        var cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StorminDB"].ConnectionString;

            using (var con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                var cmd = new SqlCommand("spAuthenticateUser", con) {CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure};

                var paramUsername = new SqlParameter("@UserName", username);
                var paramPassword = new SqlParameter("@Password", password);

                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUsername);
                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramPassword);

                con.Open();
                var returnCode = (int) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                return returnCode == 1;
            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think Form authentication can resolve your problem. In the sense if you are moving database authentication itself, it will help you role wise authentication
   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/13872/Form-authentication-and-authorization-in-ASP-NET

Comment: I know that i can user static users and webconfig, but i want to stay with Database access. Does webconfig will work when i implement that in my case?